# How to create a accordion using bootstrap but inside of that accordion I want a modal that pops up like a form also using bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5, accordion, bootstrap-accordion

I need help I want to create a bootstrap accordion but inside of that I want is a modal pop up button I made a design below. I want to modify the button so it just looks like text, and clone this exactly. I want icons down the left to symbolise the forms. the The body is just those boxes that look like an accordion header but they are smaller and is a Modal.

This is what I've done so far

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
<div class="accordion-item">
  <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
      <div>
<button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
<tr class="hover:bg-gray-50 cursor-pointer">
  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-900">
    <div class="text-sm font-medium text-brand">Centre Onboarding</div>
  </td>
  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500 text-center">
    <span class="inline-flex items-center px-3 py-0.5 rounded-full text-sm font-medium bg-gray-100 text-gray-500 border border-gray-500 mr-2">Not Started</span>
  </td>
  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500">
    <span class="mr-2">0%</span>
  </td>
</tr>
</button>
</div>
  </h2>
  <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
    <div class="accordion-body">
      Content for Accordion 1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion-item">
  <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTwo">
    <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
      Accordion 2
    </button>
  </h2>
  <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
    <div class="accordion-body">
      Content for Accordion 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion-item">
  <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingThree">
    <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
      Accordion 3
    </button>
  </h2>
  <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="<EUGPSCoordinates>headingThree</EUGPSCoordinates>" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
    <div class="accordion-body">
      Content for Accordion 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

and im using these for bootstrap

```
<!-- BOOTSTRAP -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


<!-- BOOTSTRAP TOGGLE -->
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

[image: This is the desired output, the blue links are the modal popup buttons]

[image: The blue links are the modal popup buttons]
[image: The body is just those boxes that look like an accordion header but they are smaller]